# "Доктор Фаустус": как правильно по-русски произносить фамилию Леверкюн?

Tags: орфоэпия

Мне важно для правильного чтения вслух.

На немецком Leverkühn.

Но предложение делать двойное ударение в трёхсложной фамилии мне кажется неверным.

> – На какой слог падает ударение в фамилии Leverkühn? Дело в том, что,
>   читая «Доктора Фаустуса» Томаса Манна (на русском), обнаружил, что
>   ударение на последний слог в фамилии главного героя неверно. Правильно
>   — на первый слог?
>
> – В фамилии Leverkühn  – два ударения, на первый и на третий слог, но
>   на третий - главное, более сильное. Это можно описать иначе. В русском
>   языке безударные гласные сильнее "съедаются", а в немецком более четко
>   проговариваются (если это не мурмельлаут) - тогда, мне кажется,
>   автоматически появится легкое ударение на первый слог. Кроме того, это
>   двусложное слово (состоит из двух отдельных слов), и в каждом из этих
>   двух слов есть свое ударение, при этом на третий слог - более сильное,
>   основное.
>
> Что касается Фаустуса, то в немецком языке ударение вроде бы не бывает
>   на последний/третий слог, это больше прерогатива русского,
>   французского и, наверное, каких-то еще языков. По крайней мере в
>   словах без приставок (т. е. чаще всего главное ударение на первый слог
>   корня) это вроде бы так (сорри, если я ошибаюсь, - точных правил не
>   помню, пишу больше по наитию). Получается совершенно логично: ФАустус.
>   Вспоминается в связи с этим пример типичной ошибки русскоязычных
>   людей: арбАйтен, в то время как правильно Арбайтен.
>
> – Дело-то как раз в том, что в книге есть место, где один француз
>   называет Леверкюна на французский манер с ударением на последний слог,
>   как будто он Le Vercune. Стоило ли обращать на это внимание, если и в
>   немецком основное ударение такое же?

**[источник](http://www.trworkshop.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=48083)**

---

Вот этот монолог в романе:

> — Vous maudirez l'intrus, cher monsieur Leverkuhn 2 — воскликнул он,
>   ставя ударение на третьем слоге, так, словно фамилия Адриана писалась
>   Le Vercune. — Mais pour moi, etant une fois a Munich, c'etait tout a
>   fait impossible de manquer… 3 О, я говорю и по-немецки, — перебил он
>   себя все с тем же приятным для слуха жестковатым выговором. — Не очень
>   важно, отнюдь не образцово, но достаточно, чтобы быть понятым. Du
>   reste, je suis convaincu 4, что вы отлично владеете французским: ваша
>   музыка на слова Верлена лучшее тому доказательство. Mais apres tout 5,
>   мы на немецкой почве, и до чего же немецкой, до чего уютной и
>   характерной! Я в восторге от идиллической обстановки, которой вы, cher
>   maitre, так мудро себя окружили… Mais oui, certainement, сядем, merci,
>   mille fois merci! 6
>
> 2. Вы вправе проклинать незваного гостя, мосье Леверкюн (франц.).
> 3. Но я просто не мог, очутившись в Мюнхене, не побывать… (франц.)
> 4. Впрочем, я убежден (франц.).
> 5. Но в конце концов (франц.).
> 6. Но да, конечно, сядем, спасибо, тысячу раз спасибо! (франц.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-русски фамилия читается *ЛеверкЮн*. Чтобы придать ей французское звучание нужно записать *Ля Веркюн*.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу причин для какого-то пересмотра места ударения. Да в немецком два ударения, но на русский слух очевидно, что первое - побочное, второе, на последний слог, - главное. С чем могу согласиться, для русского языка два ударения - излишество. Но пропадает-то никак не главное, а побочное.

> Вспоминается в связи с этим пример типичной ошибки русскоязычных
>   людей: арбАйтен, в то время как правильно Арбайтен.

После этого заявления желание чего-то доказывать автору пропадает. 
Правильно именно - "арбАйтен". Хотя и "Арбайт". Тут тот же случай. Ударение в немецком и по функции, и по фонетическому наполнению отличается от русского. Поэтому из двух вариантов русской транскрипции правильнее тот, который ближе русскому, ибо все тонкости немецкого не передашь все равно.